# The data are not showing up on Modal ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My problem is that the data are not displayed on the modal text fields. I was trying to solve this and i've already spent most of my hours just fixing this. I am hoping that anyone could help me with this one. I would really aprreciate your help. Here are the codes that are used to my modals.

Data will be displayed here:

```
<table id="studentList">
  <tr>
    <th>Student ID</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Course</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Home Address</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
  <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $field) {
      echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
  }?>
  <td><button type="button" name="view" class="btn btn-info btn-lg view-data" id="<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="margin:0; background-color: #1a8cff;">View More</button></td>
  <?php
   echo '</tr>';
  };?>
</table>
```

My modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div id="add-student">
        <form method="POST">
          <input type="text" id="id" name="id" placeholder="Student ID" readonly/>
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" readonly/>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" readonly/>
          <select id="course" name="course" class="course" readonly>
            <option value="">Select Course</option>
            <option value="BEED">BEED</option>
            <option value="BSED">BSED</option>
          </select>
          <select id="year" name="year" class="year" readonly>
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <option value="1">1st</option>
            <option value="2">2nd</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address" readonly/>
          <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Contact" readonly/>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" readonly/>
          <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert">
          <br>
          <br>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The script for assigning values to the modal:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){
        var student_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php";
            method:"POST",
            data:{student_id:student_id},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
                $('#id').val(data.id);
                $('#lname').val(data.fname);
                $('#fname').val(data.fname);
                $('#course').val(data.course);
                $('#year').val(data.year);
                $('#address').val(data.address);
                $('#contact').val(data.contact);
                $('#email').val(data.email);
                $('#insert').val("Update");
                $('#mymodal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
include_once '../../service/mysqlcon.php';

if(isset($_POST['student_id'])){
$query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_id = 
'".$_POST["student_id"]."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo json_encode($row);
}
?>
```

Would really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: where is the button which show the modal?

Comment: that would be on the table: <td><button type="button" name="view" class="btn btn-info btn-lg view-data" id="<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="margin:0; background-color: #1a8cff;">View More</button></td>

Comment: how look like the data?

Comment: All are in a text format, I used varchar on database(phpmyadmin)

Comment: Could you let me to see it?

Comment: Yes of course, here it is: https://imgur.com/C1Ys3U0

Comment: could you please try console.log(data) with in the success function ?

Comment: I just did and it seems to be that it was not a success. I was not able to see that it was logged on the Chrome Console.